# Chain Compatibility

Tags: chain

I am in need of a new chain, my cassette is a cs-4600 shimano and is 10 speed, will this chain I found work?

https://www.sigmasports.com/item/Shimano/Tiagra-CN-4601-10-Speed-Chain/5JZZ

The cassette is a 12-30.

Comment: Yes, it's even the same series as your cassette. Any 10s chain wll work

Comment: @JoeK: A Campagnolo chain will not work on any drive train except Campagnolo. All other standard 10 speed will.

Comment: Campagnolo works fine. It is a slightly different width but the shift is excellent. The chain is much more expensive, probably not applicable here. True, the campag 10 chain needs a special quick link, kmc make one etc.

Answer (score 3):

A 10-speed cassette will take a 10-speed chain. Any 10-speed chain from any chain manufacturer that manufactures Shimano-compatible chains(*) should work. In particular, the CN-4601 should work.

However, do note that the chain needs to be a correct length. Longer is ok as you can always shorten a chain with a chain tool, shorter is not. If it's the correct length, and if it uses a quick link, you can install it without a chain tool. If you need to shorten the chain or if it uses a reinforced connecting pin, you need a chain tool. (Plus you may need a chain tool for removing the old chain in case it doesn't have a quick link -- for quick link the correct tool is pliers.)

For example, I have a bike that has 11-30 tooth 8-speed cassette and 48 tooth big ring, plus 46cm chainstay length. The chainstay is so long it really needs a 116-link chain. A 114-link chain won't work. Also I can't switch to a 11-32 tooth 8-speed cassette or a 50 tooth big ring if I want to continue using 116-link chains.

(*): The original version of this answer told any 10-speed chain will work, but later I was told that Campagnolo 10-speed chains are slightly wider and thus could have less than optimal shifting. There are many brands making Shimano-compatible 10-speed chains such as Shimano, SRAM and KMC. It doesn't matter whether you use symmetric or asymmetric or HG-X or non-HG-X Shimano chain. I have a HG-X Shimano chain on my road bike and it works just fine, so certainly HG-X is not "MTB only".

Comment: Suggesting all 10 speed chains are the same in compatibility terms is incorrect. The asymmetric vs symmetrical Shimano designs have a bearing on performance depending on where they're used, as does HG-X versus road, as does the fact that Campy is wider, etc. It may not be how things would have ideally developed, but it's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

CN-4601 is one of the asymmetric Shimano road 10 chains. It won't play nice with a triple. You haven't provided sufficient information. In other words if you have FC-4600 or some other double, yes, but if you have FC-4603 or some other triple, no.

[image]